# AngularJS - Add 6 hours to input date to JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I don't know how can I add 6 hours to input date in AngularJS.

I've try this :

```
var eventStart = new Date ($scope.event.startdateid);
var startDate = new Date ( eventStart );
startDate.setHours ( eventStart.getHours() + 6 );

event.startdateid = new Date(startDate).toJSON();
```

But nothing happen ...

This is my HTML :

```
<input type="date" name="startdateid" ng-model="event.startdateid" min="{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
```

Can you tell me when I make mistake ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you don't need to convert nothing to `JSON` and your code seems correct (disregarding the fact that you aren't using even the *$scope* or *controllerAsSyntax* to send your variables to view -**I'll prefer to think it was just to put here in question**-), maybe you may have made some mistakes in his view.

So you just need to use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to achieve this.

Here is a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setHours = function() {
    $scope.event.startdateid.setHours($scope.event.startdateid.getHours() + 6);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="date" name="startdateid" ng-model="event.startdateid" min="{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" ng-change="setHours()">
  <hr>
  <!-- The date with +6 hours -->
  <span ng-bind="event.startdateid | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work, but I use Firebase and I think if date is not converted to JSON, I can't store her in my database ...

Comment: Thanks, I've forget a little thing but it's work like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/)?

```
moment(someDate).add(6, 'hours');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

> **One** way by doing it in **JavaScript pure**, no third party lib:

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {    
   this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000)); 
   return this;   
}
```

> Or just update the time for **6 more hours** Like your code:

```
startDate.setTime(this.getTime() + (6*60*60*1000));
```

Comment: No, it's not the only way.

Comment: @developer033 just fixed. Thanks